# Как прочитать значения в списке словарей со списками?

Tags: python, json

Есть json файлик, нужно заменить значение в num на другое, как его прочитать?

```
{
   "params":[
      {
         "id":34,
         "title":"test",
         "value":2
      },
      {
         "id":[
            {
               "num":"aaa"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: ["params][1]["id"][0]["num"]

Answer (score 1):

```
["params"][1]["id"][0]["num"]
```